# How to dynamicly change conditions in loop for Kotlin

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, kotlin, conditional-statements

My task is to remove letters from two strings one by one if there are equals and stay at the same positions.
i do this and always get index out of bound exception. can't understand how to fix indexes and make my high board dynamicly.

```
   var newSecret = StringBuilder(secret)
    var newGuess = StringBuilder(guess)    

 for (i in newSecret.indices){
            if (newSecret[i]==newGuess[i]){
                newSecret.deleteCharAt(i)
                newGuess.deleteCharAt(i)
                rightPosition++
    
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I think you're making this harder by starting with a full copy of each and then trying to remove stuff, and keep track of that new state. It's way simpler if you can build up the strings from scratch, discarding what you don't need:

```
val newSecret = StringBuilder()
val newGuess = StringBuilder()
secret.zip(guess).forEach { (a, b) ->
    if (a != b) {
        newSecret.append(a)
        newGuess.append(b)
    }
}
```

`zip` takes two iterables and gives you their elements in pairs, one from each (like a zipper bringing the two sets of teeth together). So it's perfect for situations like this where you're comparing items in the same positions.

I think that's the most readable approach up there when you want a `String` result, the general case is

```
secret.zip(guess).filterNot { (a, b) -> a == b }.unzip()
```

where `zip`ping gives you a list of pairs, and `unzip` turns that into a pair of lists. You could use that here too, but it means you have to call `joinToString("")` on each list, and then assign each component of the `Pair` to a variable... I think the `StringBuilder` version above is nicer in that case

Answer (score 1):

If you debug the code using IDE or just print statements, you will quickly realise that the index `i` is getting incremented but the length of `newSecret` and `newGuess` decreases with every `deleteCharAt` call. Hence `newSecret[i]` will give you Index OutofBoundException.

Good explanation from @gidds in the comment : `newSecret.indices` is evaluated only once, before the loop — the range is not re-evaluated when characters are deleted, which is the cause of the exception

for loop might not be the right one for this use case, you can try while loop. You have to check the index with the length of both the strings, and increment `i` only if required

```
  val newSecret = StringBuilder("abcdef")
  val newGuess = StringBuilder("abddeg")

  var i = 0
  while(i<newSecret.length && i < newGuess.length) {
    if (newSecret[i] == newGuess[i]) {
      newSecret.deleteCharAt(i)
      newGuess.deleteCharAt(i)
    }
    else i++
  }
```

Comment: Might be worth making explicit that in the question, `newSecret.indices` is evaluated only once, before the loop — the range is *not* re-evaluated when characters are deleted, which is the cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason for not changing any sort of collection while iterating through it, even if is it not part of `Collection`, `StringBuilder` clearly is a sort of collection, since it has append and deleteAt functions.

If you have a string that is `0123456789`, 0 is in index 0, 5 is in index 5. But if we remove let's say 3, then everything else after it, now has a different index. We have `012456789`, and if you count, you can see that 5 will not have index 4, and so on. That means that your procedure will not only remove things it shouldn't, but if it wants to remove index 9, well, that no longer exists, hence, index out of bounds.

There are probably other ways of doing it than this, that are much more efficient and easy to understand, but I've tried to keep the same idea as you had in your example code.

```
val newSecret = StringBuilder(secret)
val newGuess = StringBuilder(guess)

secret.withIndex()
    .filter { guess.length >= it.index + 1 //in case that guess is shorter than secret (if you know that they are the same length, this part of the predicate can be removed
            && it.value == guess[it.index] }
    .map { it.index }
    .reversed() //we want to delete from end to start, to avoid what we discussed above
    .forEach {
        newSecret.deleteCharAt(it)
        newGuess.deleteCharAt(it)
    }
```

In the above procedure, if secret and guess are:

```
 val secret = "bar1bar2x5"
 val guess = "foo1foo3y5"
```

Then newSecret and newGuess will be:

```
newSecret -> barbar2x
newGuess -> foofoo3y
```